# What am I missing? I can't figure out why it is adding the extra '.' System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near '76231'.'

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

```cs
private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String FirstName = textBoxFirstName.Text;
    String LastName = textBoxLastName.Text;
    String PhoneNumber = textBoxPhone.Text;
    String Email = textBoxEmail.Text;
    DateTime Birthday = DateBirthday.Value;
    String Street = textBoxStreet.Text;
    String City = textBoxCity.Text;
    String State = textBoxState.Text;
    String Zipcode = textBoxZipcode.Text;

    if (
        FirstName == "" ||
        LastName == "" ||
        PhoneNumber == "" ||
        Email == ""
        )
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Fields with '*' cannot be null");
    }
    else
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SER\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SunshineGrace;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO Customers
            VALUES('" + FirstName + "', '" + LastName + "', '" + PhoneNumber + "', '" + Email + "', '" + Birthday + "', '" + Street + "', '" + City + "', '" + State + "', '" + Zipcode + "'",con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Customer Added!");
    }
}
```

I'm trying to create a program that adds a column into my SQL database, I just cannot figure out why I am getting this error. I've tried reformating the insert command many different ways and changing the dateime to a textbox and its still throws the same error message.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: Agree with @marc_s about SQL injection. But also you have forgotten closing ')' on the end of command

Comment: @Quercus ....which OP would've spottet much faster and easier with the improved readability of parameterised queries

Comment: Try putting the last name in as `O'Leary` to see the first problem your code will encounter when it goes live..

Comment: And stop the lazy bad habit of NOT specifying a column list for the INSERT statement. Not certain why you need birthDATE (not day) for a customer since that is PII, but a birthdate is a date, not a datetime.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should really ***NEVER EVER EVER*** write SQL code like that! It leaves you wide open to SQL injection - the #1 vulnerability out there. Stop doing that ***RIGHT NOW***!

Instead, use **properly parametrized** SQL queries, and also get in the habit of putting your disposable objects (like `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`) into proper `using() { .. }` code blocks to ensure proper disposal.

So your code should be something like this instead:

```
// define your INSERT query and use proper list of columns in the table you're inserting into
string query = @"INSERT INTO Customers(FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber, Email, Birthday, Street, City, State, Zipcode)
                 VALUES(@FirstName, @LastName, @PhoneNumber, @Email, @Birthday, @Street, @City, @State, @Zipcode);";

// put connection and command objects into using blocks 
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SER\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SunshineGrace;Integrated Security=True"))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand (query, con))
{
    // define parameters, with their most appropriate data type, and set their values
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = FirstName;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = LastName;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@PhoneNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = PhoneNumber;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = Email;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Birthday", SqlDbType.Date).Value = Birthday;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Street", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = Street;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = City;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@State", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = State;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Zipcode", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = Zipcode;
    
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

    MessageBox.Show("Customer added");
}
```

Using this code approach not only reliably eliminates any SQL injection risk, it also prevents any errors from having too many or too few single quotes etc. in your SQL statement. It's just good practice to go with this - always.